# upload file with path stored in database jsf

Tags: jsf, jpa, upload

I'm using jsf 2 to upload file, first I upload the file in a system directory, then trying to store the path to database with other information, my stuck is that when submitting I upload the file successfully, find it in the right place, find the other information such as description, file name ... in database but don't find the path.
this is my managed bean :

```
package mbeans;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.Part;

    import daoImpl.DocDAO;
    import entities.Document;

    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class DocBean {
        public DocDAO docDAO;
        private Part file;
        private  String titreDocument;
        private  String descriptionDocument;
        private  String lien;
        private  String dateMise;
        private String Categorie;
        private String chemin;
        private String sousCategorie;
        private Integer idDocument;
        public DocBean(){
            docDAO=new DocDAO();
        }

        public String upload() throws IOException{
        file.write(getFilename(file));
        docDAO.createDoc(idDocument, titreDocument, descriptionDocument, sousCategorie, Categorie, chemin, dateMise, lien);
        idDocument=null;
        titreDocument="";
        descriptionDocument="";
        lien="";
        sousCategorie="";
        dateMise="";
        Categorie="";
        chemin +="C:\\data\\" ;

        try{

     File afile =new File("C:\\Users\\free\\Desktop\\glassfish-4.0\\glassfish4\\glassfish\\domains\\domain1\\generated\\jsp\\copy2mavenTest1111\\"+ getFilename(file));

           if(afile.renameTo(new File("C:\\data\\" +getFilename(file) ))){
            System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
           }else{
            System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
           }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return"succes";
        }
        private static String getFilename(Part part){
            for(String cd: part.getHeader("Content-Disposition").split(";")){
                if(cd.trim().startsWith("filename")){
                    String filename=cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=')+1).trim().replace("\"", "");
                    return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\')+1);
                }

            }
            return null;
        }


        public List<Document> getAlldoc(){
            return docDAO.getAllDoc();
            }

        public String getSousCategorie() {
            return sousCategorie;
        }

        public void setSousCategorie(String sousCategorie) {
            this.sousCategorie = sousCategorie;
        }

        public String getTitreDocument() {
            return titreDocument;
        }

        public void setTitreDocument(String titreDocument) {
            this.titreDocument = titreDocument;
        }

        public String getDescriptionDocument() {
            return descriptionDocument;
        }

        public void setDescriptionDocument(String descriptionDocument) {
            this.descriptionDocument = descriptionDocument;
        }

        public String getDateMise() {
            return dateMise;
        }

        public Integer getIdDocument() {
            return idDocument;
        }

        public void setIdDocument(Integer idDocument) {
            this.idDocument = idDocument;
        }

        public void setDateMise(String dateMise) {
            this.dateMise = dateMise;
        }

        public String getCategorie() {
            return Categorie;
        }

        public void setCategorie(String categorie) {
            Categorie = categorie;
        }

        public String getLien() {
            return lien;
        }
        public void setLien(String lien) {
            this.lien = lien;
        }


        public Part getFile() {
            return file;
        }
        public void setFile(Part file) {
            this.file = file;
        }
        public String getChemin() {
            return chemin;
        }
        public void setChemin(String chemin) {
            this.chemin = chemin;
        }

    }
```

my dao that is used to store information about the file in database :

```
    package daoImpl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import entities.Document;

@Stateless

public class DocDAO {

    private static EntityManager em;
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;


    public DocDAO() {
        if(factory==null)
            factory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mavenTest");
        if(em==null)
            em=factory.createEntityManager();
    }
    public List<Document> getAllDoc() {
        List<Document> listeDoc;
        Query q;
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        q=em.createQuery("select d from Document d ORDER BY d.dateMise");
        listeDoc = q.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return listeDoc ;
    }
   public void createDoc(Integer idDocument, String titreDocument, 
            String descriptionDocument, String sousCategorie
            , String Categorie, String chemin, String dateMise, String lien) {

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Document f =new Document();
        f.setIdDocument(idDocument);
        f.setDateMise(dateMise);
        f.setDescriptionDocument(descriptionDocument);
        f.setLien(lien);

        f.setTitreDocument(titreDocument);
        f.setCategorie(Categorie);
        f.setSousCategorie(sousCategorie);  
        em.persist(f);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    }
}
```

and finally y xhtml page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head></head>
<body>

 <h3>ajouter un nouveau document </h3><br/>
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1">
        <h:outputText value="Nom du document"> </h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{docBean.titreDocument}"></h:inputText><br/>
        <h:outputText  value="description"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{docBean.descriptionDocument}"></h:inputText><br/>
        <h:outputText  value="chemin"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{docBean.chemin}"></h:inputHidden><br/> 
        <h:outputText  value="Date de la mise "></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{docBean.dateMise}"></h:inputText><br/>
        <h:outputText  value="Lien"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{docBean.lien}"></h:inputText><br/>
        <h:outputText  value="Catégorie"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{docBean.categorie}"></h:inputText><br/>
        <h:outputText  value="sous catégorie"> </h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{docBean.sousCategorie}"></h:inputText><br/>
        <h:outputText> télécharger le document</h:outputText>
        <h:inputFile value="#{docBean.file}"></h:inputFile><br/>
        <h:commandButton value="valider" action="#{docBean.upload}"/>
    </h:form>

</body>                   
</html>
```

thanks.

Comment: For multiserver application this approach is not very good: one server may not access to system directory of second server. Better way to store image in database as BLOB. Each application server has access to DB and can read data from it.

Comment: What I upload is not only images but pdf, texts, images ... so I choose to move uploaded file to a specific directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any f.setChemin(chemin) in the DocDAO class.  That may be the problem if the path is not set somewhere else in your Entity.

Comment: thanks I didn't make attention.It store empty String in database not the path which is : chemin="C:\\data\\"+getfileName(file)

Comment: Did you try adding f.setChemin(chemin).?  If so, did it solve your problem?

Comment: also I directly put "C:\\data\\"+getfileName(file) in the method in the managed bean and it is stored to database as :                       docDAO.createDoc(idDocument, titreDocument, descriptionDocument, sousCategorie, Categorie, "C:\\data\\"+getfileName(file), dateMise, lien);